# SetAutoClose did not work as expected

Tags: nsis

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "license.txt"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
;Confirmation Page
Page custom Confirmationpage
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

This is what I have in setup.nsi file at he beginning. at the end of the installation I am prompting user to install other software. If user chooses to install the second software, initial software (which was installing) should go silent and disappear as soon as it finishes installing.
Here I tried to set

```
SetAutoClose true
```

But it ignores my SetAutoClose setting and brings up the finish page, prompting user to hit finish (which I do not want). Any one can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoclose only works when instfiles is the last page.

If you don't want to show the finish page based on some condition just call `quit` in a section or skip the page:

```
Var NoFinishPage

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE maybeskipfinish
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English


Section "Other software"
ExecWait '"c:\foo\bar.exe" /baz'
StrCpy $NoFinishPage 1
SectionEnd

Function maybeskipfinish
${If} $NoFinishPage = 1
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```